# Get subscribers count on YouTube

Tags: php, mysql

I have an site where I use this code for get the count of subscribers:

```
$user = $_GET['url'];
$data = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$user");
$split = explode("subscriberCount='",$data);
$split2 = explode("'",$split[1]);
echo $split2[0];
```

New YouTube don't give me anymore real time updates of the count, how can I change that in my code to show me a count even if not in real time.

I found this but i not understand very well :(

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5966

Comment: Don't understand the question. The count is still there. You're saying they don't give real time updates anymore, but you want something to get a count even if not in real time?

Comment: OP, do not use PHP short tags. You are asking for troubles as it can be turned off. Long tags can't.

Comment: no... i have 700 subscribers on youtube (youtube update the click after 48h), if somebody's click subs in my channel the count still remains 700, I adedd in my site one buttons were show how much i have, but i want when click in my site this button, to show the count +1 as right..

Comment: [The YouTube Data API (v2) is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_deprecated). If you need support down the road, use [v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Answer (score 0):

Google added this *"Feature"* because they had troubles to eliminate fake watches - so some people opened via Tools through Proxies and raised the Counter quick... if one proxy was burned (the number did not changed - use other Proxy)

So they don't update this in real time - and there is no API to get this in real time ...

So I'm sorry, but i have to tell you that there is no way to implement this.